# What should the scale show?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

> If $g=10 N/kg$ , what will show the Scales?
>
> Yes, I know this is a very simple problem. But, I am stuck.
> $$P=mg \Rightarrow m=\frac{100N+100N}{10N/kg}=20 kg .$$

But, I'm worried about this answer. What's the difference between hand holding the scales and putting them on the table? I think, if the Scales is captured manually, the force applied from above should be meaningless. And answer must be $m=10 kg.$ Is it correct?

Comment: This is not a question about mathematics, but a question about physics.

Comment: Should I delete question?

Comment: I actually don't know. I have voted to have it moved to [physics.SE], but for that to take effect, more people need to agree with me and actively vote to have it moved.

Comment: I understood. Sorry for this. I hope the question is not downvoted. I made mistake..

Comment: Hold the scales vertical, with one weight pulling straight down, and the other pulling down via a pulley (i.e. pulling straight up, as far as the scales are concerned). Then what do you think?

Comment: @hdhondt $100N$ or $10kg$ ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is $10 kg$. When you apply Hooke's law to one end of a spring: $F=-kx$, it is implicit that the other end is fixed in place by a force $-F$. This force may be applied by the wall, hand, another mass, etc...

Answer (score -1):

The idea is that when you would hang $1\mathrm{kg}$ in a massless basket under a scale, the scale would show that $1\mathrm{kg}$ in the basket. We do know Newtons second law that force equals mass times acceleration: $F=m a$. We know the gravitational acceleration on earth at sea level is approximately $g=10\mathrm{m/s^2}$ this tells us that the force being exerted for $1\mathrm{kg}$ is $10\mathrm{N}$.
Now you have to imagine the other way around, when I have a force of $100\mathrm{N}$ pulling on both sides, what would the scale show now? It would show the same conversion but now the other way around so: $m=\frac{F}{a}$ with in this case $a=g$. So $F=200\mathrm{N}$ and $a=10\mathrm{m/s^2}$ gives $m=20\mathrm{kg}$.

Comment: I think your answer is wrong.  Answer must be $10 kg$